# A minimal Gmail text editor / word processor?

Tags: gmail, text

Gmail is my favorite text editor. It autosaves (in the cloud). It's browser-based. All I have to do to share with a friend is press send.

But opening a new window is difficult - especially while browsing elsewhere or using a different app.

And the New Message window, once opened, cannot be collapsed into a narrow column. It's a little clunky.

Also, it tells *all* (or none) of my friends I'm awake.

Is there a web app (or client) that is compatible with Gmail (maybe even has chat), and functions as a minimal text editor?

Comment: You set chat visibility to invisible if you don't want anyone to know you are awake.

Comment: Have you looked into Thunderbird? http://www.getthunderbird.com

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I was being a little tongue-in-cheek there (maybe you were too?), but have edited the statement you refer to.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal - Regularly used Thunderbird 2 years ago. Does it now autosave drafts in the cloud?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that you can set it up to auto-save every x minutes (see Preferences -> Composing), and you can set drafts to be saved in an IMAP folder (see Accounts -> Copies and folders).

Comment: Why does Google Drive not work? Same idea of text editing, and sharing documents uses contact information associated with your Google (hence Gmail) account.

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for something accessible in osx?   Might want to clarify your OS requirements (or if you only want browser-based).

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "text editor".

If you want an osx gmail client that has solid, wysiwyg editing capabilities (and a really nice user interface, try [Sparrow](http://www.sparrowmailapp.com/mac.php). Google bought them, but it still seems well-supported enough.

If you meant a true plaintext editor, there are a ton, but I find both Byword and iaWriter to be minimal enough to kill distractions, but with decent markdown support.